# Change value of character variables based on their value using R

Tags: r, dataset, character

I have a character variable containing country names. For some, I need to change the name of the countries to merge it with another data set.

How do I change for example "Bahamas, The" to just "Bahamas"? I tried:

`` BD_WB$`Country Name`= " Bahamas, The" <- "Bahamas" ``

But it changed the whole content of BD_WB$`Country Name` to "Bahamas".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
BD_WB$`Country Name`[which(BD_WB$`Country Name` == "Bahamas, The")] <- "Bahamas"
```

This selects the values of the `Country Name` column that are "Bahamas, The", and corrects only those values to "Bahamas".